# How to get the currency symbol from Locale Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to make a computed property that show all possible currencies to be shown on a UIPickerView. Currently, the symbols I get in my array always is ¤ any tips to make it work?

```
import UIKit

struct MyCurrency: Codable {
    let code: String
    let name: String
    let symbol: String
}

var currencies: [MyCurrency] {
    return Locale.Currency.isoCurrencies.compactMap {
        guard let name = Locale.current.localizedString(forCurrencyCode: $0.identifier),
              let symbol = Locale(identifier: $0.identifier).currencySymbol  else { return nil }
        return MyCurrency(code: $0.identifier, name: name, symbol: symbol)
    }
}

print(currencies)
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that `Locale.Currency` is new in iOS 16 beta (and other current beta OS versions)

Comment: Yes, sorry for not specifying I am in a pre-release version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through the locales, and get currency code with this you can get all the rest

```
var currencies: [MyCurrency] {
    return Locale.availableIdentifiers.compactMap {
        guard let currencyCode = Locale(identifier: $0).currencyCode,
              let name = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent.localizedString(forCurrencyCode: currencyCode),
              let symbol = Locale(identifier: $0).currencySymbol  else { return nil }
        return MyCurrency(code: $0, name: name, symbol: symbol)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. Sadly, this code will need a different solution soon since Locale(identifier: $0).currencyCode is now deprecated on iOS 16.0. If someday I need to update the code, I post it here